# A box contains 10 pairs of shoes (20 shoes in total). If two shoes are selected at random, what it is the probability that they are matching shoes?

Tags: probability, combinations

> A box contains $10$ pairs of shoes ($20$ shoes in total). If two shoes are
> selected at random, what it is the probability that they are matching
> shoes?

I saw people answering this question with the answer of $\frac{1}{19}$.
But I don't understand why we cannot also reason that the two shoes (that are a pair) are picked at the same time out of the $20$ shoes, hence it's $\frac{2}{20}$ or $\frac{1}{10}$.

Comment: How many pairs of shoes could you pick in total? It also depends whether you are picking in a way which ensures you get one left shoe and one right shoe (in which case $\frac 1{10}$ would be correct).

Comment: Are they 10 pairs of identical (color/size/style and all attributes) shoes or 10 pairs of distinct shoes? For the former, do you consider any Left + Right pairing a valid matching pair?

Comment: The way we get probabilities is not by picking two numbers arbitrarily from the numbers given in the problem and dividing one by another. If you claim the answer is $1/10,$ you should be able to describe $10$ different ways the shoe-selecting can proceed (exactly one of which gives you a matching pair) and give a plausible reason why the $10$ ways are each equally as likely as each other. Or $20$ different equally likely ways, of which exactly two give you a matching pair. Do you have any reasons like these?

Comment: To be fair, the original problem is rather vague. Do you reach in and choose two shoes that are next to each other? Did someone thoroughly mix up the shoes inside the box beforehand so that the matching pairs are not next to each other? Are there actually ten different kinds of shoes in the box? We make a lot of assumptions in a problem like this in order to make it answerable.

Comment: my reasoning for $\frac{1}{10}$ answer is that i picked a certain pair (2 shoes) from 20 shoes, so it should be  $\frac{2}{20}$, or  $\frac{1}{10}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you first pick a shoe, then the probability that the next shoe you pick comes from the same pair as the first shoe is $1/19$.

The number of ways two shoes can be selected from $20$ shoes is
$$\binom{20}{2}$$
Ten of these choices form a matching pair, so the number of favorable cases is $10$.  Hence, the probability of selecting a matching pair of shoes is
$$\frac{10}{\binom{20}{2}} = \frac{10}{190} = \frac{1}{19}$$
To get an answer of $1/10$, you would have to set the rules so that you always pick a left shoe and a right shoe, as Mark Bennet indicated in the comments.